# Error in converting a user input into a float number

Tags: python, string, loops

```
magnitude = input("Enter the value of magnitude: ")

for mag in magnitude:
    if float(mag) <= 1.9:
        print(mag1)

    elif float(mag) <= 2.9:
        print(mag2)

    elif float(mag) <= 3.9:
        print(mag3)
```

If I do any input with a decimal I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  line 36, in effects
    if float(mag) <= 1.9:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'
```

I've tried converting the original input statement to a float before my loop but it just gives me a different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Python 3.x, `input()` gives you a string, hence `magnitude` is a string.

When you do `for mag in magnitude:` , you are iterating over every character in the input string, hence if you input something like `5.4`, `mag` will first be `5` then `.` then `4` . This causes the issue when you try to convert `'.'` to float.

If you are inputing a single decimal number, you do not need a loop, you can simply do -

```
try:
    if float(magnitude) <= 1.9:
        print(mag1)
    elif float(magnitude) <= 2.9:
        print(mag2)
    elif float(magnitude) <= 3.9:
        print(mag3)
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Input")
    #Handle invalid input the way you like.
```

Assuming `mag1`/`mag2`/`mag3` are defined previously.

---

If your input is space separated decimal numbers, like `5.4 4.5 ...` , then use `.split()` on the string to split based on any whitespace (so that you get a list of all numbers) and then iterate over the split list, Example -

```
for mag in magnitude.split():
    try:
        if float(mag) <= 1.9:
            print(mag1)

        elif float(mag) <= 2.9:
            print(mag2)

        elif float(mag) <= 3.9:
            print(mag3)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input")
        #Handle invalid input the way you like.
```

Again assuming `mag1`/`mag2`/`mag3` are defined previously.

Answer (score 0):

The function `input` always gives you a string. In this case you're trying to iterate over a string. If you change this value to a float, you'll going to get a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Python strings operate as sequences, where each character is an element.
So if you enter the string "2.5", the line `for mag in magnitude:` will iterate through each character in turn.

For example:

```
magnitude = "2.5"
for mag in magnitude:
    print mag
```

will yield:

```
4
.
9
```

The characters `4` and `9` can be coerced into number types, but `.` can't, which causes your error.